# KWin "Walk through windows of current application" doesn't cycle

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, kwin, task-management

When using the "walk through windows of current application" shortcut it opens the right interface but doesn't cycle through all windows.

Just the one. If I press the same combination again *(or reverse)* it does nothing

If I'd have to guess, I'd say that it recognizes the windows switcher as current application and it just freezes.

Options:

[image: Options for switch application]

Comment: I get the same problem, did you manage to find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: Nop, I'm no longer using kwin, but couldn't solve this during my experience

Answer (score 0):

Using Plasma 5.15.4, I noticed that walking through windows of current application only walks through 2 of them. But backwards cycling does cycle through all windows, so you could use that as the standard key shortcut.